# Method to draw 3-connected planar graph on a sphere

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-drawing

The [Tutte embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_embedding) is a way to create a "nice" drawing of a 3-connected planar graph in the plane, after having chosen an outer face.

Is there a similar method to draw such a graph on a sphere? [Steinitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz%27s_theorem) suggests that such a drawing is possible.

Of course, we could just map the planar coordinates to a sphere with some arbitrary projection, but this does not produce a "nice" drawing, e.g. it will not reflect the natural symmetries of the graph, and will not produce a dodecahedron for a dodecahedral skeleton. While "nice" is not a very well defined term, I assume there must be some existing work on this topic.

Comment: [Circle packings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem) are often used for this. See in particular the [Generalizations section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem#Generalizations).

Comment: This might help: Aleardi, Luca Castelli, Gaspard Denis, and Eric Fusy. "Fast spherical drawing of triangulations: an experimental study of graph drawing tools." In *17th Internat Symp Experimental Algorithms*. 2018. [PDF download](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2018/8959/pdf/LIPIcs-SEA-2018-24.pdf)

Comment: Another reference: Perry, Scott, Mason Sun Yin, Kathryn Gray, and Stephen Kobourov. "Drawing graphs on the sphere." In *Proceedings of the International Conference on Advanced Visual Interfaces*, pp. 1-9. 2020.

Answer (score 8):

If the graph $G=(V,E)$ has a lot of symmetries, then using **spectral realizations** might give you nice drawings that reflects these symmetries. The success of this method (e.g. whether the drawing is planar, whether all vertices are on a sphere) depends on a lot of factors, some of which are not completely clear to me. However, what I can tell you is that it works for the graphs of all uniform 3-polytopes (so, e.g., the dodecahedron).

I explain the most straight forward way to do it, some tweaks might be neccessary for the general case:

> **Costruction.** Let $\theta$ be an eigenvalue of (the adjacency matrix of) $G$, and $v_1,v_2,v_3\in\Bbb R^n$ three ortho-normal eigenvectors to $\theta$. Construct the matrix $M:=(v_1,v_2,v_3)\in\Bbb R^{n\times 3}$ with the $v_i$ as columns. The rows of that matrix are a 3-dimensional embedding of the vertices of $G$.

Usually, you should take $\theta_2$, i.e., the second-largest eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of $G$. Surprisingly, this eigenvalue has multiplicity three for most symmetric graphs that come from 3-polytopes (exceptions are, as far as I know, only prisms). This means, you cannot do anything wrong by choosing just any orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

Here is code for Mathematica to automatically find a nice drawing of the dodecahedral graph:

```
G = GraphData["DodecahedralGraph"];

A = AdjacencyMatrix[G];
n = VertexCount[G];
eval = Eigenvalues[A // N];
th2 = RankedMax[eval, 2];
evec = NullSpace[A - th2*IdentityMatrix[n]];

GraphPlot3D[G,
    VertexCoordinateRules -> Table[i -> evec[[{1,2,3}, i]], {i, 1, n}]
]
```

Output:

[image]

If $\theta_2$ has multiplicity $<3$, you can add eigenvectors of other eigenvalues until you have three, preferably from the next largest eigenvalues. Just do not use the largest eigenvalue.

---

For your example in the comments (the capped cube), we have the problem that $\theta_2$ has multiplicity one. However, as explained, we could use eigenvectors of $\theta_3$ (which has multiplicity two) to complete to a set of three vectors. Use this:

```
th2 = RankedMax[eval, 2];
th3 = RankedMax[eval, 3];
evec = NullSpace[A - th2*IdentityMatrix[n]] ~Join~ NullSpace[A - th3*IdentityMatrix[n]];
```

Output:

[image]

For general graphs one should certainly follow a more dynamic approach, e.g. sorting the eigenvectors by their eigenvalues and taking the largest three (but not the largest one). Something like this:

```
vec = SortBy[Transpose[Eigensystem[A // N]], First][[{-2, -3, -4}, 2]];

GraphPlot3D[G,
    VertexCoordinateRules -> Table[i -> vec[[;; , i]], {i, 1, n}]
]
```

Comment: I was having an awful time to reproduce this at first (before you posted code) because `Eigenvalues` and `Eigenvectors` seem to give a different ordering when taking the numericized version of this specific matrix ... `Eigensystem` is fine though.

Comment: It would seem that this works if the graph has a drawing with enough rotational symmetries. That's when there will be an eigenvalue with multiplicity 3.  This was the first example that I naively constructed, expecting that your method would not work: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aJE76.png Call it a box-house with a roof. It turns out that there _is_ an eigenvalue with a multiplicity of 3, and using it leads to this non-obvious drawing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1dUqw.png

Comment: @SzabolcsHorvát I managed to get a decent picture by taking the second and third largest eigenvalue. I extended my answer to include that example. I recommend always taking the largest eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, it does usually work well. `layout[g_?GraphQ] :=
 
 Module[{am = N@AdjacencyMatrix[g], evec, eval, ord},
  {eval, evec} = Eigensystem[am];
  ord = Reverse@Ordering[eval];
  Graph3D[g, 
   VertexCoordinates -> Transpose@Part[evec, Take[ord, {2, 4}]], 
   PlotLabel -> Take[eval[[ord]], 4]]
  ]` then `Print@*layout /@ 
 Select[PolyhedronData[#, "Skeleton"] & /@ PolyhedronData[], 
  ConnectedGraphQ]`

Comment: This is actually implemented in Mathematica as `GraphLayout -> "SpectralEmbedding"`.

Comment: @SzabolcsHorvát That's good to know! Thanks. It seems to be implemented differently as I obtain slightly different results.

Comment: There should be a spherical version of Tutte's method.  Can every vertex lie at the spherical barycenter of its neighbours?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay What I can say for sure is, that if one uses only eigenvectors to a single eigenvalue $\theta$ to construct the realization, then it holds $$\sum_{j\in N_i(G)} v_j=\theta v_i,$$ where $v_i$ is the embedding vector of the $i$-th vertex, and $N_i(G)$ is the set of neighbors of $i$. So the vertices are indeed in some kind of balanced configuration. Of course a vertex is not in the barycenter of its neighbors, because then it would not be on the sphere, but it is in the *span* of the barycenter.

Answer (score 3):

I am working on this, work in progress. Algorithm determines a separating circle and maps that onto 4 spherical edges of 6 of unit sphere tetrahedron. Basically Tutte algorithm on polar coordinates is used twice, with separating circle as "outer face". No problem for vertical angles [0°..180°], but horizontal angles [0°..360°) have overlap problem. I solved that by forcing separating circle angles to [0°..270°] for left side of separating circle vertices, and use Tutte algorithm for that. Then I add 360° to vertices with horizontal angles [0°..90°], which results in angles [180°..450°], and use Tutte algorithm for right side of separating circle vertices. Here is an example embedding of C36.10 fullerene (10th of 15 non-isomorphic C36 fullerenes generated with plantri52):
[image]

More details [here](https://stamm-wilbrandt.de/en/#pgp).